# Multiple apps with a shared db, what should I use to make it?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am pretty new to programming and have so far only learnt HTML, CSS and a little bit of javascript and Jquery.  What I would like to do is make a website which has a variety of apps (both web and mobile).  All of these apps would need to share a DB with the website, not only for login but also various forms of data each app deals with.

A friend suggested to me that I should be using AngularJS with Firebase and just make one big app with all the apps and website included in that, but I would rather a more flexible option so the app doesn't become huge.  So I would rather have a website which links to each app but also has access to the data.

So I have a few questions regarding this:

1 - What languages would I best to use to make this?

2 - If I went with angular and firebase for each app would I be able to use a language like php or rails to also tap into that db?

3 - What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Marty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , I'm making a big app like you and I've searched a lot and the easiest way is to use angular and php
although u can do better than this.
For example for your backend , you can use NODE.js , but its a matter of your knowledge and timing and how much energy you want to spare and consume.(But if you use php the right way , its very lightwaight/simple/fully supported/well known/free)

Angular is very wasy to learn and fast to use , and also PHP , because both od them have been tested and fully supported with lots of communities(thats very important)

for learning Angular Go to egghead.com , you can find lots of interesting angular video learning for free , And also you can simply search the youtube